# How to run a Java program by using an S function in Simulink?

Tags: java, matlab, simulink

I am making a program where I need to take values collected from a Simulink model and pass them into a Java program. I set up a Level 2 S function in Matlab, where I instantiate an instance of the class I need to pass the values to. Once I have those values, I want to pass them to my object within the Update function. However, my program does not recognize my object in the Update function.

```
function Start(block)

    gameObj = javaObject('millerek.lafayette.edu.Game'); %set up game
    gameObj.main("");
%end Start

function Update(block)
    X = block.InputPort(1).Data(1,1);
    Y = block.InputPort(1).Data(2,1);
    javaMethod('getMdlValues',gameObj,X,Y); 
    %gameObj.getMdlValues(1,0);  %test. This did not work either
%end Update
```

I have tried using javaObjectEDT and javaMethodEDT, but they did not work.

I am able to successfully create my object when Simulink is run. I get an error from Matlab when Update is executed, saying that it does not recognize my object(and so getting a null pointer exception). I believe this is because I create my java object in the Start function and call its main there, but I try to pass the values in the Update function, so perhaps the object is being treated like it's local? I've added the jar file that I'm using to the static class path in Matlab. I am not sure how to get Matlab to treat it like it's global. Thank you for taking the time to help, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What does "this did not work" mean?  Be specific.  You do get the data using `InputPort.Data`.  When you create the object in the Start Function where do you store it, and how do you access it in the other methods?

Comment: Hi Phil, so I went back to the documentation and figured out my data collection problem- I was trying to handle 2D data and I forgot to include block.AllowSignalsWithMoreThan2D = 1;  . However, when the program is run now, I get: Undefined function or variable 'gameObj'. I added the two functions that handle all the Java parts in my question. Thanks for taking the time to look at my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each S-Function method is a function in its own right.  Specifically it has its own memory and does not share memory with other methods.

With a Level-2 M-Code S-Function, where the data you want to share is not a basic/fundamental data type (i.e. not a double, or int, etc) then the easiest way to do this is to use the UserData property of the block's RunTime object.

So, in your `Start` method you want to store the object

```
set_param(block.BlockHandle,'UserData',gameObj);
```

Then in your `Update` method you get the object using

```
gameObj  = get_param(block.BlockHandle,'UserData');
```

You almost certainly also need to implement a `Terminate` method to destroy the java object at the end of the simulation.

Comment: Thanks for the help! At the end of my S function, I have `function Terminate(block)`.